# React component, why are half your props undefined on form submit?

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs, ecmascript-6, undefined

New to React, hope this isn't something terribly obvious. I've been beating my head against the wall for a while.

According to React Dev Tools in Chrome, ALL of form's props are defined and what I expect them to be. Even when the form is submitted. Great.

Unfortunately, within handleSubmit(), only 2 of them are visible: **id**, and **name**. **Person** and **value** are both *undefined*, despite showing up with the correct values in Dev Tools.

Why in the world are half (and only half) of the props showing up as *undefined*?

```
  import React, {Component} from 'react';
  import {
  TextField,
  IconButton,
  FlatButton,
  DatePicker,
  Snackbar,
  RaisedButton,
  LinearProgress,
  Dialog,
  DropDownMenu,
  MenuItem,
  AppBar
} from 'material-ui';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import EditAttachFile from 'material-ui/svg-icons/editor/attach-file.js';
import NotificationSync from 'material-ui/svg-icons/notification/sync.js';
import EventNote from 'material-ui/svg-icons/notification/event-note.js';

class NameFirstForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: props.person.getAttr('nameFirst')};


    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.setState({value: nextProps.person.getAttr('nameFirst')});
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    console.log("value", event.target.value);
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.save.call(this.props.ctx, event);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <form 
        onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
        name="nameFirst"
        id={this.props.person.getAttr('id')}
        person={this.props.person}
        value={this.state.value} 
      >
        <MuiThemeProvider>
          <TextField 
            name="nameFirst"
            id={this.props.person.getAttr('id')}
            person={this.props.person}
            value={this.state.value} 
            underlineStyle={ {color: 'rgb(0,188,212)' } }  
            floatingLabelFixed={true} 
            floatingLabelText="First Name" 
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
        </MuiThemeProvider>
      </form>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default NameFirstForm;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is reading the values from the Form. What I see is that you could just return the object with the correct value from your state and your properties like this:

```
handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.save.call(this.props.ctx, {
      person: this.props.person,
      id: this.props.person.getAttr('id'), //You could skip this if you already have the person object
      newValue: this.state.value
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks Damian, do you have any idea why only half of the props are showing up in handleSubmit()? I'm re-reading the React docs trying to figure out where I went wrong...

Comment: If you mean by half properties that you see in handleSubmit only name and id, you have a misunderstood about how React works. What you get in handleSubmit is a Form HTML Element, id and name are normal properties for the Form Element. Person is not a normal property for Form, that's why you don't see it in handleSubmit. Anyway the correct way to handle the values from the Form should be by your state variables, properties or directly from the inputs using ref. Check this example It will help you to understand how works https://plnkr.co/edit/GPGTJYE2Rlbcyzj5HYTo?p=preview